# How to add an icon for the new app in the NEW iTunes Connect

Tags: app-store-connect

I can't find any way to add an icon for my new Mac OS X app in the new iTunes Connect. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/1c1lA.png

No Edit or Choose File or Upload link or button. I use Safari, the latest version...

And even uploaded binary doesn't have an icon: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Up1gA.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading https://devforums.apple.com/community/ios/distribution/itc I realised that I have to submit the app to review to see the icon. And indeed after that the icon appeared... Ufff....